# Repository.findAll() in Spring Data for Apache Cassandra will output error "argument type mismatch"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I created two tables in CQL to Cassandra.
I use org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository.

In one table (memobox), repository.findAll(); can be successfully acquired,
In the other table (departments), repository.findAll(); can not be successfully obtained, and the following error is output.

Is there any good advice?

■Project structure

SpringBoot + Spring Data for Apache Cassandra

Version:

- Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.5.RELEASE)
- spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE
- cassandra 2.1.16

■Error log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:133) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:115) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.read(MappingCassandraConverter.java:200) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraConverterRowCallback.doWith(CassandraConverterRowCallback.java:47) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:565) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.selectAll(CassandraTemplate.java:311) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.findAll(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:104) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.findAll(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:36) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
```

■Successful table：describe memobox

```
cqlsh:keyspacea> describe memobox;
CREATE TABLE keyspacea.memobox (
id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
date timestamp,
memo text,
name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX memobox_memo ON keyspacea.memobox (memo);
CREATE INDEX memobox_name ON keyspacea.memobox (name);
```

■Unsuccessful table：describe departments

```
cqlsh:keyspacea> describe departments;
CREATE TABLE keyspacea.departments (
department_id varint PRIMARY KEY,
department_name text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

■Source is below

https://github.com/hidetarou2013/SpringBootDBSample

branch is feature/cassandra

■Entity:MemoBox

```
package com.example.cassandra.entity;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs;

@Table(value = "memobox")
public class MemoBox {

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id",ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private UUID id = UUIDs.timeBased();

@Column(value = "name")
private String name;

@Column(value = "memo")
private String memo;

@Column(value = "date")
private Date date;
```

■Entity:Departments

```
package com.example.cassandra.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;
@Table(value="departments")
public class Departments {

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "department_id",ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private int department_id;

@Column(value = "department_name")
private String department_name;

public Departments(int department_id,String department_name){
    this.department_id = department_id;
    this.department_name = department_name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private List<Employees> emp = new ArrayList<Employees>();
```

Comment: Can you post your `JpaRepository` for both the entities?

Comment: [Link:Repository:MemoBoxRepository2](https://github.com/hidetarou2013/SpringBootDBSample/blob/feature/cassandra/src/main/java/com/example/cassandra/repository/MemoBoxRepository2.java)

[Link:Repository:DepartmentsRepository](https://github.com/hidetarou2013/SpringBootDBSample/blob/feature/cassandra/src/main/java/com/example/cassandra/repository/DepartmentsRepository.java)

Comment: Try running your code without department's constructor.

Comment: Thank you Abdullah Wasi. it's solved !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Department` constructor is having the problem. Remove the `Department` constructor.